# Add a query on each access to DB via TableAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, tableadapter, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a project which accesses a SQL Server database using `TableAdapters`, in which I now have to implement the following: before each and every access to the database, I have to add a `SELECT` query with the username of the user who's logged in.

Adding a new `TableAdapter` with that query is the obvious solution. However, there are hundreds of accesses to the DB, and having to add that call before each access is tedious. So I'm looking for a solution that will minimize the changes I have to make in the code.

I tried adding a constructor, with the query call in it - I thought I could add a constructor (using a `partial class`), add the query call to that constructor, and call my new constructor instead of the default one. But then I noticed that I don't call the constructor before each access, and that means that the query wouldn't be executed before each database access.

I wanted to use an event,  but the only available events are `RowUpdating`, `RowUpdated`, and `FillError`, all of which happen *after* returning from the database, and they only happen on a filled dataset (and not on scalar functions).

So how can I add a new query, with minimum code changes?

Comment: just an idea.. maybe you can define a base class with that sql statement, and all the other request should extend that class, and then you can just override a function and in the first line just add the base() call...
You can also define triggers in yor sql DB, you can trigger the event on every access to specific tables just fire an event which is your select query

Comment: Thanks, @LiranBo. The other requests use the relevant `TableAdapter` class, so it can't extend any class... Regarding the trigger - we considered that, however, the data we want to select isn't available in the DB, we have to pass it from the code

Comment: is the `TableAdapter` class sealed? if not you can extend it and use it as base class... I googled it and found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233697.aspx), maybe it can help.

Comment: Thank you again, @LiranBo. What you suggested is using a `partial class`, which I considered, but it would still mean changing all the places in the code which use the `TableAdapter` class, to use the new functionality in the partial class